# .htaccess - Remove "/demo/" from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

*i*'m updating my site in new version for demo version.
I just keep my demo site as `www.domain-name.com/demo/`

Now i'm gonna keep my site in demo folder.. so if access `www.domain-name.com` it'll fetch file from "demo" folder

for that i used below coding.

```
RewriteRule ^(index.php)$ ./demo/ [L]
```

it will affect only root path other path it won't.

I need to change as below

**from**

```
 http://www.domain-name.com/demo/index.php/contact-us
 http://www.domain-name.com/demo/index.php/aboutus
 ....etc
```

**to**

```
http://www.domain-name.com/index.php/contact-us
http://www.domain-name.com/index.php/aboutus
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to keep it in the demo folder? Also, your example is the wrong way around, I think.

Comment: i don't want do wasting my time to delete Old datas... that's Y..

Comment: Well, you're already waiting 17 minutes, just saying ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change the DocumentRoot (in the main server configuration)

```
DocumentRoot /foo/bar/demo/
```

Answer (score 0):

For .htaccess this should work

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect direct requests to /demo subfolder  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} demo/
RewriteRule ^demo/(.*) http://www.domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# map everything else to subfolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ demo/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you say something like this?

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /demo/$1 [L]